# How to run my android test project on commit of the android app

Tags: android, svn, jenkins

I followed the directions here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project to set up my jenkins build for my test project. This project will automatically run when anything is checked in to my subversion project.

The problem is that I also want to run my tests when someone commits to the android app. There doesn't seem to be room for multiple build triggers like there is for other items on the Jenkins config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under post-build actions at the end of the Jenkins set up, you select build other projects, then pick your test project.